# Como faço para enviar dados para um servidor socket que já foi iniciado dentro de uma AsyncTask?

Tags: java, android, socket, asynctask

Já consegui conectar com o servidor pelo aplicativo, receber e mostrar os dados enviados por ele. Também não há problemas em mandar mensagens para o servidor. **O problema é: depois de estabelecida a conexão, capturar dados de um editText e enviar esses dados para o servidor que foi aberto na AsyncTask.**

Classe que utilizo para abrir a conexão, ouvir e imprimir o que o servidor manda:

```
private class ConexaoSocket extends AsyncTask<String, String, Void>{

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(String... args) {
            try {
                Socket servidor = new Socket("192.168.0.20", 3232);
                try {
                    PrintStream saidaServidor = new PrintStream(servidor.getOutputStream());
                    Scanner s = new Scanner(servidor.getInputStream());

                    while (s.hasNextLine()) {
                        publishProgress(s.nextLine());
                    }
                    s.close();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                servidor.close();
            }catch (Exception e){
                e.printStackTrace();
                System.out.println("Erro: "+e.getMessage());
            }
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onProgressUpdate(String... s) {
            if(s.length > 0){
                txvRetornoSocket.setText(s[0]);
            }
        }
    }
```

Se alguém tiver alguma ideia de como resolver isso e puder me ajudar, fico muito grato.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consegui resolver o problema, só é preciso criar uma `saidaServidor` visível para toda a classe com `private PrintStream saidaServidor` e criar um método para ser chamado no `onClick` do botão que quiser enviar os dados de um `editText`, por exemplo. Declarei o método da seguinte forma, dentro da AsyncTask:

```
public void enviarParaServidor(String s){
    saidaServidor.println(s);
}
```

Daí, depois de já executado e iniciado o servidor com a chamada da AsyncTask, é possível, facilmente, chamar o método para enviar os dados para o servidor, pegando uma `String` de qualquer lugar, inclusive de um `editText`, da seguinte forma: `instaciaDoObjetoDaClasseQueHerdaAsyncTask.enviarParaServidor(string_vinda_de_qualquer_lugar)`. No meu caso, o objeto instanciado é da classe `ConexaoSocket` e se chama `cs`, além disso, pego a os dados de um `editText`. Portanto, dentro do `onClick` do botão, meu código ficou o seguinte:

```
cs.enviarParaServidor(editText.getText().toString());
```

Espero ter ajudado alguém, 
;)